# How do I find Quantum Fisher Information from an array of fidelity values for various parameter values?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-fisher-information

I have an array of Fidelity values corresponding to parameter values.

For example,

eps=[0,0.1,0.2....,1]

where eps is the parameter

Fid=[1.0, 0.9, 0.96, 0.91, 0.85, 0.78, 0.71, 0.65, 0.59, 0.54]

I know quantum fisher information is negative of second derivative of fidelity wrt to the parameter. However, I get some negative and some positive values of the QFI. But the QFI is always non-negative, then where am I going wrong.

If you can attach a Qiskit code, even better.

An example of the Fidelity wrt to parameter (The red and green dots are of two different systems, it does not matter here). We see that the fidelity values lie between 0 and 1 as expected, but it is not a monotonic function. Hence, the second derivative will go below zero and above zero in different places on the graph. [image]

Comment: how did you try to calculate it that produced a negative result?

Comment: I plotted fidelity wrt to epsilon. It gives me value between 0 and 1 as expected. I take second derivative of the fidelity with respect to the parameter. As fidelity is not expected to be monotonic function, how can we expect that the fisher information will have same sign throughout. I hope you are able to visualize it.